# Is there a way to start vector indexing from 1 in c++?

Tags: c++

Just wanted to know that , If there is any way to start indexing of a vector or an array from 1 in c++ . I am not talking about pushing some random at index 0 and then carrying out work with starting at index 1 . I mean actually starting from 1.

I thought it may be possible after overloading the [] operator and decrement the value of index by 1 inside it . So that if I write my_vector[1] , it should mean(internally) my_vector[0],i.e., 0th index element. Is there any other way in standard template library itself?

Comment: Besides adding a dummy zero element that you never use? None. But please don't, it will only confuse everybody else. And why do you want this? What is the actual problem you need to solve by doing this?

Comment: what's the purpose of achieving this?

Comment: No, just get used to 0 indexing.

Comment: Trying to fake 1-based arrays is error-prone.  Either you risk falling of the edge at the high-end (thus invoking undefined behavior), or erroneously using index 0 when you were not supposed to.

Comment: some equations and formulas are simpler with 1-based index, some with 0-based indexing. It is just a matter of convention, the important thing is to be consistent, and as someone already made the choice for you, you can only add confusion for not being consistent or live with it

Comment: fwiw, I used to translate fortran code to c++ as an exercise, fortran had 1based arrays so I had to be extremely careful with translating the code not to mess up the indices. It was a worthwhile exercise, but I never would want to have 0-based and 1-based indices in the same code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Just wanted to know that , If there is any way to start indexing of a vector or an array from 1 in c++

No.

What you can do is define a custom container of your own with an overloaded operator[] that behaves as you would like.

On the other hand, consider carefully whether this is a good idea. Even if it may feel simpler to you, it will be confusing to others.

Comment: often "others" includes yourself when you look at your own code after a week or so ;)